# Memory error in iGraph Python when adding large number of edges

Tags: python, graph, network-programming, igraph

Regarding this thread : http://goo.gl/uEyFua

I am experiencing a quite similar issue with the following code, trying to import a large Graph :

```
for (edge_id) in cursorSQL:
 L.add((edge_id[2], str(edge_id[1])))

g = igraph.Graph.TupleList(L)
```

I get the following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "C.py", line 707, in __getitem__  return self._ids[item]
KeyError: '184840900'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
     g = igraph.Graph.TupleList(L)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\igraph\__init__.py", line 2473, in TupleList

  edge_list.append((idgen[item[0]], idgen[item[1]]))

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\igraph\datatypes.py", line 709, in __getitem__
  self._ids[item] = next(self._generator)

     MemoryError
```

Just to make it clear. This code works perfectly until number of edges is too large (~4millions.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to python-64bits, and problem is now solved.

Problem was the 2GB-per-process limit in win7 for python-32bits.